# Excel vba to interleave cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I found the below code and would like some help on how can I add columns by cell value instead of having the number of columns hardcoded like below.

```
Sub MergeColumnsAlternating()
  Dim total, i, rowNum As Integer

  total = 4 '' whatever number of rows you need to merge.
  i = 1

  For rowNum = 1 To total
    Range("D" & i) = Range("A" & rowNum)
    i = i + 1
    Range("D" & i) = Range("B" & rowNum)
    i = i + 1
    Range("D" & i) = Range("C" & rowNum)
    i = i + 1
  Next rowNum
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Perhaps you can edit your question after you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want the number `4` to not be hard coded? You could type that number in cell A1 and change `total = 4` to `total = Range("A1").Value`. That way, you can change A1 from 4 to 8 and then run your subroutine to loop through 8 rows

Answer (score -1):

A `Range` is a collection of `Cells`. The smallest collection consists of a single item. Therefore a single `Cell` is also a `Range'.

You can define a `Range` by its address, by a given name, or by the address of it's first and last `Cell`s.  *A1:D4* uses this latter method. VBA adopts this addressing method and can handle it like a name, e.g. `Range("A1:D4")`. The same syntax can be employed to define a single cell range, like `Range("A1")`, and that's where your trouble starts.

By defining a `Cell` like a `Range` you give up the advantage offered by VBA in exchange for the perceived simplicity of treating cells and ranges alike as Excel does. You end up with a concoction like `Range("A" & i)` and, logically inevitable, the question of how you can place the column in a variable. Of course, that could be done, too. But the much easier way is to address cells as cells, not as ranges.

A `Cell` is a member of a `Cells` collection. Such a collection comprises of all the cells in a defined range. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells` defines a collection of all the cells in *Worksheet("Sheet1")*. Simply `Cells` defines the collection of all cells in the `ActiveSheet`. Within the collection a cell is defined by its coordinates: `Cells([Row], [Column])`. This is different from cell referencing by range name at worksheet level where the column is defined first. `Cells(4, 1)` specifies the cell A4.  Therefore it is an alternative to `Range("A" & 4)`. It's neater, faster to process and both coordinates are fully exchangeable for calculated variables. For example, please figure out which cells are defined here:-

```
Dim R As Long
Dim MyCell As Range
R = 8
Set myCell = Cells(R, Cells(4, 1).Value)
' or
Dim Temp As Variant
Temp = Cells(R, Cells(4, 1).Value).Value
```

In both cases, the cell's row is defined by the variable `R` (usually a loop counter as you go through a column of values) while the column is defined by the value of A4. You can see that `Cells(4, 1)` could itself be defined by variables as well. It's noteworthy that A4 might contain a column number or letters defining a column (such as "A" or "AB"). And I draw your particular attention to the fact that the first example defines a cell - a range - while the second merely adopts the `Value` of that range. This is a very common, sometimes controversial, subject which it is good for you to be aware of.

Your code's `Range("D" & i) = Range("A" & rowNum)` jumps right in the middle of this controversy. The range in column D is made equal to the range in column A, and the question is whether this means that one cell will be equal to the other or the one cell adopts merely the `Value` of the other. `Value` is a `Range`'s default property (meaning VBA will presume it if omitted) and VBA would normally decide the likely meaning by the data type of the receiving variable. In this case the receiver is a `Range` object. Therefore the entire `Range` object should be copied, and the obvious question is why no `Copy` method was used. (In fact, to assign an object to an object the `Set` instruction is required. Since it's omitted in your code it's likely that the `Value` only will be copied. The code is ambiguous and different versions of Excel may execute it in different ways.)

Now, how assigning all the properties (or its `Value`) of one range to another might lead to "MergeColumnAlternating" is beyond my pay grade. But, perhaps the above answer to your question will enable you to make sense of your code. Good luck!